# Can an unsigned long long int be used to store the output from clock64()?

Tags: cuda

I need to update a global array storing clock64() from different threads atomically. All of the atomic functions in CUDA support only `unsigned` for `long long int` sizes. But the return type of clock64() is signed. Is it safe to store the output from clock64() in an `unsigned`?

Comment: What documentation are you looking at? They look like they work on unsigned to me.

Comment: @Hurkyl [link]http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#atomicexch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various [atomic functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) which support atomic operations on `unsigned long long int` (ie. a 64-bit unsigned integer), such as `atomicCAS`, `atomicExch` and `atomicAdd`.  And if you have a cc3.5 or higher GPU you have even more options.

Referring to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function) on `clock64()`:

> long long int clock64(); when executed in device code, returns the value of a per-multiprocessor counter that is incremented every clock cycle.

So, since it is a 64-bit signed quantity, it is bit-wise identical to an `unsigned long long int` until it becomes negative.  Let's assume the counter is reset to zero either at the start of your kernel, the start of the cuda context, or machine power-on.  This counter will not become negative until around:

2^63(cycles)/1,000,000,000(cycles/s) = ~292 years after whichever of the above events is the actual reset point.

(I'm using 1GHz here as an estimate of the GPU core clock)

So for the first 200-300 years (after machine power-on, let's say), the `clock64()` function will not return a negative value.  So I'd say it's pretty safe to consider it as "always" positive, and therefore always identical to `unsigned long long int`, meaning you can safely cast it to that, and use it in one of the atomic functions that support `unsigned long long int`.

On the other hand, it's probably not safe to cast it into an `unsigned` quantity.  That arithmetic would be:

2^32(cycles)/1,000,000,000(cycles/s) = ~4 seconds (after machine power on)

So in about 4 seconds, the `clock64()` function will numerically exceed the value that can be safely recorded in an `unsigned` quantity.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation ! I meant storing output from clock64() into an `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: I'm quite puzzled by this sentence in your question: "None of the atomic functions in CUDA support `unsigned` for `long long int` sizes."  I've stated my position in the first paragraph of the answer.  Are we looking at the same documentation?  The link that you provided to Hurkyl lists a `unsigned long long int` prototype for `atomicExch`.

Comment: My bad. Edited my original question.